# Помогите найти ошибку в коде C# DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

Заполняю `DataGrid` из Excel, после мне нужно сравнить заполненный `DataGrid` с базой данных, чтобы не дергать базу каждый раз создал еще один временный, и в процессе проверки, если поле во втором `DataGrid` отсутствует нужно выделить его другим цветом, а если присутствует то просмотреть совпадают ли нужные мне данные в нем, если что-то не совпадает, нужно покрасить ячейку.

Проблема заключается в том, что в поле где нужно красить только ячейки, а остальное оставить как есть, код красит ячейки правильно но и строку тоже закрашивает.

Вот мой код, как его сделать эффективнее?

Код обработчика кнопки:

```
dgvTemp.DataSource = exp.GetProduct();

dgvTemp.Columns["price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N4";

string NeedSku = "";
for (int i = 0; i < exDgvData.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    NeedSku = exDgvData.Rows[i].Cells["Код"].Value.ToString().Trim();

    for (int k = 0; k < dgvTemp.Rows.Count; k++)
    {
        if (dgvTemp.Rows[k].Cells["sku"].Value.ToString().Trim() == NeedSku)
        {
            if (dgvTemp.Rows[k].Cells["price"].Value.ToString().Trim() != exDgvData.Rows[i].Cells["Цена"].Value.ToString().Trim())
            {
                paint(i, "Цена", false);
            }
            if (dgvTemp.Rows[k].Cells["model"].Value.ToString().Trim() != exDgvData.Rows[i].Cells["Модель"].Value.ToString().Trim())
            {
                paint(i, "Модель", false);
            }
            if (dgvTemp.Rows[k].Cells["quantity"].Value.ToString().Trim() != exDgvData.Rows[i].Cells["Количество"].Value.ToString().Trim())
            {
                paint(i, "Количество", false);
            }
        }
        else
            paint(i, "", true);
    }
}
```

Код метода `paint`:

```
private void paint(int RowsID, string ColumnName, bool All)
{
    Color defultCellColor = exDgvData.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor; 

    if (All)
    {
        exDgvData.Rows[RowsID].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }
    else
    {
        exDgvData.Rows[RowsID].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = defultCellColor;
        exDgvData.Rows[RowsID].Cells[ColumnName].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил созданием массива элементов для определения нужных мне строк. Но все же это неэффективно.